# Custom filter crashes on Kurento 6.4.0 for Chrome Version 49.0.2623.75 (64-bit)

Tags: kurento

I am using Kurento 6.4.0 and with a custom filter. I am trying a modified version of group call example which works fine on Firefox browser but KMS crashes when connected with Chrome browser Version 49.0.2623.75 (64-bit).

following is the error from the log file:

```
(kurento-media-server:13579): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_debug_log_valist: assertion 'category != NULL' failed
[31;1mSegmentation fault [0m (thread  [33;1m140298602628864 [0m, pid  [33;1m13579 [0m)
Stack trace:
 [34;1m[gst_mini_object_unref] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0 [32;1m:0x6A230 [0m
 [34;1m[kurento::module::vadcustomfilter::VADCustomFilterImpl::~VADCustomFilterImpl()] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmsvadcustomfilterimpl.so.0 [32;1m:0x140EA [0m
 [34;1m[kurento::module::vadcustomfilter::VADCustomFilterImpl::~VADCustomFilterImpl()] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmsvadcustomfilterimpl.so.0 [32;1m:0x14439 [0m
 [34;1m[std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release()] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmscoreimpl.so.6 [32;1m:0x8E279 [0m
 [34;1m[std::_Function_handler<void (), std::_Bind<void (*(kurento::MediaObjectImpl*, std::string))(kurento::MediaObjectImpl*, std::string)> >::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&)] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmscoreimpl.so.6 [32;1m:0x94449 [0m
 [34;1m[boost::asio::detail::completion_handler<std::function<void ()> >::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service*, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long)] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmscoreimpl.so.6 [32;1m:0x94BF0 [0m
 [34;1m[boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&)] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmscoreimpl.so.6 [32;1m:0xA1C9F [0m
 [34;1m[kurento::WorkerPool::StaticConstructor::StaticConstructor()] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmscoreimpl.so.6 [32;1m:0x9C6AB [0m
 [34;1m[std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Bind<void (*(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service>))(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service>)> ()> >::_M_run()] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmscoreimpl.so.6 [32;1m:0xA04B8 [0m
 [34;1m[std::this_thread::__sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1l> >, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >)] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [32;1m:0xB1A40 [0m
 [34;1m[start_thread] [0m
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/nptl/pthread_create.c [32;1m:312 (discriminator 2) [0m
 [34;1m[clone] [0m
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S [32;1m:113 [0m
```

Is there any problem with the browser version or is there something wrong with my KMS filter which is causing this crash ?

**Edit 1:**

Error on browser console:

```
local candidate{"candidate":"candidate:2695668549 1 tcp 1518280447 172.24.12.10 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag K1UwPCWKobEHgN2y","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}

conferenceroom.js:398 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2695668549 1 tcp 1518280447 172.24.12.10 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag K1UwPCWKobEHgN2y","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0},"name":"someone"}

conferenceroom.js:399 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.sendMessage @ conferenceroom.js:399Participant.onIceCandidate @ participant.js:198EventEmitter.emit @ kurento-utils.js:531(anonymous function) @ kurento-utils.js:166
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is on the destructor of your `VADCustomFilterImpl` it tries to unref something that probably is already released.

**Edit:**

If you are storing buffers for future process, you should call `gst_buffer_ref` while storing and `gst_buffer_unref` when you are done in order to release it.

Comment: checked the destructor, looks like there is a race condition. I am dealing with gst_buffer which gets unref/NULL. is there any way I can avoid race condition ?

Comment: Depends on how you are using the buffer. In general if you are going to keep a buffer you should increase a reference.

Comment: okay, is there any method which we can use to get refcount of gst_buffer ?

Comment: Try to search a little bit yourself before asking. Googling for "gst_buffer ref" I found https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstBuffer.html

Comment: yes I am looking into https://developer.gnome.org/gstreamer/stable/gstreamer-GstBuffer.html 

what I said was is there any method by which I can get the integer reference count ?

Comment: Why do you need the reference count?